# Creating 3 Dynamic Threads,But 3 threads calls the Same function (Method1) but i want to call each thread to call 3 different functions Simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 Thread[] tr = new Thread[Max];    //Creating three Dynamic Threads
 for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
     {
        tr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method1));
        tr[i].Start();
        tr[i].Name = String.Format("Thread_Name:{0}", i);
     }

 void Method1()    //Function Name
 {

           WinOpTableAdapters.attendanceTableAdapter tx;
           tx = new WinOpTableAdapters.attendanceTableAdapter();

           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
           DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
           dt = tx.GetDataAll(Convert.ToInt32(TxtNumbers.Text),"8/16/2012","11/10/2014");
           double counts = dt.Rows.Count;
  }
```

Creating Dynamic Threads based on input,But Dynamical created threads calls the Same function (Method1) but i want to call each thread to call  different functions Simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `for` cycle? But probably you want something different :)

```
Thread[] tr = new Thread[3];    //Creating three Dynamic Threads

tr[0] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method1));
tr[0].Start();

tr[1] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method2));
tr[1].Start();

tr[2] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method3));
tr[2].Start();
```

And remember that there is no "Simultaneously"... There is no guarantee that they will be executed at the same time. If there is only one single logical processor in your PC, executing three things at the exact same time is clearly impossible!